# Display latest item from an XML file that contains specific string in the <title> node - jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I am currently appending data from a XML file to a specific div on my page and displaying the latest "article". I am looking to display the latest "article" containing a specific string in the title so I can use one XML file and present different data in different portions of my site.

The code I am currently using is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(document).ready(function()
              {
                        jQuery.get('news.xml', function(RSSblogs){ 

                jQuery('.module').append('<div class="newDiv" />');

                        jQuery(RSSblogs).find("item:lt(1)").each(function(){ // DISPLAY LATEST ARTICLE

                            var headline = jQuery(this);
                var $enclosure = headline.find('enclosure');
                var image = $enclosure.attr("url");
                    var headlinesTitle = headline.find('title').text();
                    var link = headline.find('guid').text();
                    var description = headline.find('description').text();
                    var teaser = headline.find('comments').text();
                        var blogData = '<img src="' + image +'" height="172px" width="306px" >';
                blogData += '<a href="' + link + '" > <h1> ' + headlinesTitle + '</h1> </a>';
                            blogData += '' + teaser + ' <br clear="all" />';
                blogData += '<a href="' + link + '" class="mainButton" ><span>FULL STORY &rsaquo;</span></a>';


                    jQuery('div.newDiv').append(jQuery(blogData));

                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

This line of code is displaying the latest article

```
jQuery(RSSblogs).find("item:lt(1)").each(function(){
```

I am looking to display the latest based on a string in the headlinesTitle variable which is the  node in the XML. I am just not sure which selector to use.

Comment: I was able to use the contain selector to get it to work. I am not sure if it s the best way, but it works. `jQuery(RSSblogs).find("item:contains('specific text'):lt(1)").each(function(){`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the contain selector to get it to work. I am not sure if it s the best way, but it works.

```
jQuery(RSSblogs).find("item:contains('specific text'):lt(1)").each(function(){
```